# PhantomJS Url fail to load for unknown reason

Tags: url, redirect, web-scraping, phantomjs

Here is the URL I'm trying to load with PhantomJS :  http://shop.karinelecchi.fr/collections/jupes-robes/products/jalousie

Here is my code :

```
var fs      = require("fs");
var system  = require("system");

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;+http://www,google,com/bot.html)";
page.settings.loadImages = false;
var url = "http://shop.karinelecchi.fr/collections/jupes-robes/products/jalousie";

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
 console.log(msg);
};
page.open(url, function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    console.log('Yiha! load the address!');
    phantom.exit(); 
}
});
```

My output : "Unable to load the address"

Any guesses? Thx

Comment: And what's your output? When you ask for help, please, add as much info as you can. You can't go to the doctor telling "something hurts me somewhere" xD

Comment: Done! :) I thought that the title was sufficient...

Comment: Try PhantomJS 2 if you don't do this already.

Comment: Ok. What OS do you have? What PhantomJS version? Have you tried your script to load another website, like google.com? How do you populate `url`? Can we see the rest of your code?

Comment: Edited! OS X Yosemite. Yes I tried with a lot of websites and It load successfully! PhantomJS version 1.9.7

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a website that explains how to track down url load fails: https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/getting-to-the-bottom-of-why-a-phantomjs-page-load-fails/

Just in case the site goes down, I'm going to copy here important details on how to track down those problems:

Just before calling page.open() add the following code:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    page.reason = resourceError.errorString;
    page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
};
```

Now you can print out the reason for a problem in your page.open() callback, e.g.:

```
page.open(
    "http://www.nosuchdomain/",
    function (status) {
        if ( status !== 'success' ) {
            console.log(
                "Error opening url \"" + page.reason_url
                + "\": " + page.reason
            );
            phantom.exit( 1 );
        } else {
            console.log( "Successful page open!" );
            phantom.exit( 0 );
        }
    }
);
```

This script outputs the following:

```
Error opening url "http://www.nosuchdomain/": Host www.nosuchdomain not found
```

Remember that `page` also has an `onError` event where you can get more info.

Comment: I get this : Error opening url "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0640/6395/products/JALOUSIE_dark_back_medium.jpg?v=1427300416": Operation canceled

Comment: Some options for this: You are using PhantomJS 1.9.X or you have problems with SSL, so you have to start your command line with this: `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false`. EDIT: Just saw you comment above.

Comment: More things. The cancelled one is an image, so check if removing `loadImages = false` works.

Comment: I tried the SSL command line and I removed loadImages = false and I still have my problem...